# MS Word: chapter numbers within captions reset to 0 despite displaying correct chapter number in the dialogue box

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I'm editing a document for a coworker, and one of the things I've fixed is inconsistent headers. After defining my list styles and getting the headings just right, I've continued to encounter a few problems, such as Heading 2 resetting to the incorrect chapter number after I save and close the document. Everything has been solvable so far, except for this problem:

All the captions I've inserted so far have worked perfectly, but partway through a chapter they stopped. The first table is correctly captioned "Table 6.1 - ...", but subsequent tables will not caption correctly. When inserting the caption, the dialogue box displays "Table 6.1" instead of "Table 6.2," and once inserted the caption reads "Table 0.1."

I'm running Word 2007. Any light you can shed on this issue is much appreciated! This problem starts on the 6th page of the chapter and continues until the end of the chapter.

Edit: I've narrowed it down to a specific table. Everything before Table 6.2 works, and nothing after does until the start of the next chapter.

Comment: Is change tracking enabled - that can interfere with sequence numbers. If so, accepting all changes will probably fix it this particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround delete the offending caption, then copy and paste another, working, caption into its place.

The pasted caption should retain the numbering scheme and correctly display as 6.2.

If that doesn't work, try deleting the table and retyping it.  Make sure you delete all hidden text and paragraph markers between the text and the table.

Something is causing the numbering to reset.  It is often a wild goose chase to track down exactly what is causing it.